Self-polar triangle with two sides a secant has third side a secant?
This is from Coxeter Projective Geometry, see http://voutsadakis.com/TEACH/LECTURES/PROJECTIVE/Chapter10.pdf page 13 , an incidence table of a projective plane with 31 points and lines ($PG(2,5)$). A cone is the locus of self-adjoint points of a hyperbolic polarity. Now, every secant of a given conic (a line with two points of the conic on it) is part of exactly two different self-polar triangles (I understand that), but the author claims that they are of 'a different type'. One self-polar triangle will have 3 secants as sides and the other only one (the other sides not intersecting the cone), thus a configuration in which both self-polar triangles have exactly two secants as sides is impossible. Why would that be? I really can't think of a reason.

Simply a matter of adding up the numbers. A conic has $6$ points. Exactly $6$ lines go through a given point, a line has at most two points of a conic and (dually) at most two tangents of the conic go through a given point. Suppose you have a self-polar triangle with two sides a secant and the remaining side containing no point of the conic. Let $P$ be the vertex where the secants meet and $Q$ and $R$ be the other vertices. Of the lines through $Q$, $PQ$ is a secant and the lines connecting $Q$ with the points of the conic on the image (under the polarity $\alpha$ determining the conic) of $Q$ will be tangents (this should be clear). Every point of the conic lies on a line through $Q$ and cannot be $Q$ (because then the triangle would not be self-polar), so it must be that of the three remaining lines through $Q$ two will have $0$ points of the conic and one (but not $QR$) will have $2$ points of the conic. Same reasoning for lines through $R$ and this will give you at least $3$ additional points of the conic where $4$ were given from the start, which is impossible since the conic only has $6$ points. If I remember correctly, you also have to show that a self-polar triangle always will have at least one secant as a side, this can be done with a similar argument, but the argument is more intricate. However, remember that, by duality, no tangent can go through a point that is the image of a line with no points of the conic on it, therefore the points of the conic will be per two on $3$ lines through that point. Let $l$ be a line with no points of the conic on it (so, not a secant nor a tangent) and $L$ its image under the polarity $\alpha$ that defines the conic. $L$ does not lie on $l$ (otherwise $l$ would be a tangent). Let $k$ be one of the $6$ lines through $L$. $k$ is not a tangent (has zero or two points of the conic on it, see above) so $\alpha(k)$ not on $k$. Now $L$ on $k$ so $\alpha(k)$ on $l$, and is not the meeting point $k.l$ of $k$ and $l$. Therefore $L$, $\alpha(k)$ and $k.l$ form a self-polar triangle ($\alpha(KL)=\alpha(K).\alpha(L)=k.l$). We can repeat with one of the $4$ remaining lines through $L$ etc. and we see that $l$ is a side of $3$ different self-polar triangles (and they are the only ones, since every self-polar triangle with $l$ as a side must have two sides through $L$). Suppose that one of them does not have secants as sides, then another one of them must have exactly two secants as sides (since $3$ of the lines through $L$ are secants, the other $3$ have no point of the conic on them), which cannot be the case as has been shown above.
